# Why Doesn't External Triggering of System Beep Trigger Hooked Code?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, hook

This code works as expected with the "cin" line removed and the "Beep(750, 300);" uncommented: the beep is "caught" by the hook function.

When I run this as is, I open another shell, and hit control-G, followed by enter, which triggers the system beep- but that beep doesn't seem to be triggering the print statement in this code. I also tried a Sleep(30000), but that didn't work either.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mhook-lib/mhook.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Goal: detect use of 'beep' function via hook

// Define _Beep in order to dynamically bind to the function (what function???)
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *_Beep)(DWORD, DWORD);

// Backup the address of the Beep function, as it will need to be restored after hooking
_Beep BackupAddress_Beep = (_Beep)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "Beep");

// This is the function that will be inserted just before the Beep function once the hook is in place
BOOL WINAPI HookBeep(DWORD dw_freq, DWORD dw_duration) {
    printf("***** Call to Beep(%u, %u).\n", dw_freq, dw_duration);
    // Continue the chain: send Beep the required params
    return BackupAddress_Beep(dw_freq, dw_duration);
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[]) {
    //HANDLE hProc = NULL;

    printf("Testing Beep.\n");
    if (Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&BackupAddress_Beep, HookBeep)) {
        // What happens if an external program initiates the beep, rather than ourselves? Loop until keyboard break?
        //Beep(750, 300);
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        // Remove the hook
        Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&BackupAddress_Beep);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The console is owned by another process, conhost.exe.  It acts as a security boundary, preventing other apps from doing something evil like snooping passwords out of the console buffer.  And yeah, to defeat api hooking attacks :)

Comment: I did some research. From what I read, in order to do what I want, I'd need to place hooks in every process, because kernel32 (which contains Beep) is copied into each process that uses it; its not as if you can hook one instance of it and expect that to be used in all cases. (Well, except maybe for modifying the kernel32 file on disk).